# Android Switch Widget: Setting android:track causes thumb and track to not show up

Tags: android, xml

I am having trouble customizing the look of an Android Switch widget. I have custom xml drawables that I want to use for the thumb (the little button part that usually says On or Off) and the track (the background that the thumb slides across). When I set just the thumb using android:thumb, it works fine. When I set the track (whether or not the thumb is set), the switch disappears entirely and I'm left with only the text showing.

Here is my code when just the thumb is applied:

```
<com.blahblahblah.blah.CustomSwitch
    android:id="@+id/switch_1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textOff="Off"
    android:textOn="On"
    android:text="Something Awesome"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:thumb="@drawable/custom_switch_thumb" />
```

Here is what it looks like in the preview window:

[image]

And with the track applied:

```
<com.blahblahblah.blah.CustomSwitch
    android:id="@+id/switch_1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textOff="Off"
    android:textOn="On"
    android:text="Something Awesome"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:track="@color/track_color" />
```

Preview window with track applied:

[image]

For reference I am using Android Studio 0.2.3 on OSX 10.7.5.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I just stumbled upon the same problem and found a fix through on the [HoloEverywhere issue tracker](https://github.com/Prototik/HoloEverywhere/issues/522). You'll need to set the `<size>` of the drawable XML shape you are using.

Not working (the widget is there and I can interact with it, but I can't see it, it's hidden):

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:shape="rectangle">

  <solid android:color="@color/black_50" />
</shape>
```

Working (not the added `<size>`):

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:shape="rectangle">

  <solid android:color="@color/black_50" />
  <size android:width="56dp" android:height="20dp" />
</shape>
```

Comment: I only had to add a height to fix it. e.g. <size android:height="48dp">

Answer (score 0):

In general just for changing an image you don't need to subclass a control you can style it e.g. with the style attribute.

About your problem there are several controls which expect a drawable and not a plain color. In the control definition (the xml part) you can just define that you allow a reference but you cannot limit it to drawable references. So just avoid to use colors directly. If you don't want to add a image you could also define it with xml, but note that this does not work in all cases.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I know I don't need to subclass the control, but I'm doing that across the board for this particular application. It shouldn't affect anything, especially not at this point, because my subclasses only have overridden constructors that just call super(...) and don't do anything else.

I've tried a drawable and just a color. I have yet to find a case where a color does *not* work when a drawable is preferred. It's always worked in all other cases. In this particular case, using a drawable or a color, neither one works. It works fine for thumb, but not for track.